# Ruby on Rails - Debug Purposes - Add file name (partial/view) to HTML output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning Spree Ecommerce. Although I ask this with Spree as an example, I think it is useful elsewhere as well.

In spree we have many views defined by the admin section. You can override them via `Deface` gem if you know which view you need to override. Other than `Deface` you can simply put a physical file with the same route and Rails will use it instead of the one provided by the Gem.

Either way, you need to know which view you need to override.

When you look in to a page/view, you have many smaller partials making one whole page.

My interest is, is there a way to find which section was created by which partial.

For example, some thing like:

```
<!-- /route/to/view.html.erb -->
<div id="something">
   <!-- other html -->
</div>
<!-- end of /route/to/view.html.erb -->
```

I hope you got my point, some maker to know that a specific html segment was generated by a specific view/partial.

So this way, I can know/debug easily.

Thank,

Appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try [xray](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails), I'm using it with Spree and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

xray is nice, but a bit "loud". i use this snippet in my rails3.2 apps: https://gist.github.com/phoet/1386152

```
if Rails.env.development?
  module ActionView
    class PartialRenderer
      alias_method :rails_render, :render

      def render(context, options, block)
        msg = "rendering '#{options[:partial]}' with locals '#{(options[:locals] || {}).keys}'"
        "<!-- start #{msg}-->\n#{rails_render(context, options, block)}\n<!-- end #{msg}-->\n".html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## UPDATE

i made a gem [partially_usefull](https://github.com/phoet/partially_useful) out of this gist

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: i don't like copying code. it feels wrong to me, so i keep posting links.

Comment: I think this is clear enough: "Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes". There are rules to follow here on SO, it's not a matter of taste.

Comment: it's only a suggestion and not a rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use this gem ['current_template'](https://github.com/shihokambara/current_template).

It fetch name of the current template (partial) from log/development.log file.

Comment: or 

simply add

 ```<%= "#{`tail log/development.log`}".scan(/\s[a-z]+\/\S+/) %>```

to your layout/application.html.erb.